# How i can use wcf in a wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mobile

Hi I have a wpf applicacion to reserve hour to a car service and I want to have a mobile application, how I can make a synchronize booth application.
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WPF is a computer-software graphical subsystem for rendering user
>   interfaces in Windows-based application.
>
> WCF is a set of APIs in the .NET Framework for building connected,
>   service-oriented applications.

There is a cool [blog post](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-visual-studio/how-consume-wcf-service-using-wpf) about how you can implement a WCF service and then consume it using a WPF client.

Comment: Link was broken.

Comment: @BohdanKuts Yeap, fixed that. Thanks.